# add value in IndexedDB using Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, indexeddb

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

***Prefer Links***

[ngx-indexed-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db)

***Search related to Links***

[Getting error while adding value to indexedDB using angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406173/getting-error-while-adding-value-to-indexeddb-using-angular2)

I want to add data in **`indexeddb`** but somehow database connection open error is display. I have attached a screenshot.so I request put on answer one small example add value in **`indexeddb`**.
[image]

**My code**

***`app.components.js`***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxIndexedDB } from 'ngx-indexed-db';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'indexDb-Angular';


  ngOnInit() {
    let  db = new NgxIndexedDB('DVdb', 1);
    db.openDatabase(1, evt => {
      let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore('people', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });

      objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
      objectStore.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: true });

    });

    db.add('people', { name: 'Sumit', email: 'Sumit@test.com' }).then(
      () => {
          // Do something after the value was added
      },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
      }
  );
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to make the `db.add(...)` as async after the `db.openDatabase` ?

Comment: how to use async in ngOnInit() ??

Comment: Not on `ngOnInit()` but the `db.openDatabase` is made async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `openDatabase()` an async method so that it waits for database to open up before adding a value. You can make it async by using `.then(function() {`

```
ngOnInit() {
    let  db = new NgxIndexedDB('DVdb', 1);
    db.openDatabase(1, evt => {
      let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore('people', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });

      objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
      objectStore.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: true });

    }).then(function () {
        db.add('people', { name: 'Sumit', email: 'Sumit@test.com' }).then(
          () => {
              // Do something after the value was added
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: yes. you are right .second one is an optional callback that will handle the creation of objectStores for that version if needed. openDatabase returns a promise.

Comment: what do you mean added value?